# Word unscrambling using python

Tags: python, words, scramble

The following code scrambles the text randomly using step size, i want to write a function to unscramble and get the original string how to do it.

```
def scramble(plain):
    cipher = ""
    step = 7
    for x in range(0, step):
        for y in range(x, len(plain), step):
            cipher += plain[y]
    return cipher
```

Comment: It doesn't scramble it "randomly", it scrambles it with a very noticeable pattern.  Try scrambling the letters of the alphabet, starting with the first 7 letters, then adding one letter at a time, and see the resulting pattern.  Look for the pattern, and try writing the unscramble function yourself.  If you have specific issues with your unscrambling code, we can try to help.

Comment: sorry i recognized the pattern could u help me figure it out how to reverse it I'm unable get a hold of it any clue would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the pattern:

```
def unscramble(cipher):
    plain = [""] * len(cipher)
    step = 7
    i = 0
    for x in range(0, step):
        for y in range(x, len(plain), step):
            plain[y] = cipher[i]
            i += 1
    return ''.join(plain)
```